# Proof of the identity $\|A\|_{\infty}=\max_{1\le i \le n}(\sum_j |a_{ij}|)$

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

$\def\norm#1{{\Vert#1\Vert}_{\infty}}$
I do not completely understand the steps of the below proof. The result establishes that $\norm{A}=\max_{1 \le i \le n}\sum_j |a_{ij}|$. Any inputs or comments that could help me follow the proof to the end, would be really helpful.

> **Theorem 7.11** (Burden and Faires - Numerical Analysis).
>
> Prove that
>
> $$\norm{A}=\max_{1 \le i \le n}\sum_j |a_{ij}|$$

Proof.

We first prove that

$$\norm{A} \le \max_{1 \le i \le n}\sum_j |a_{ij}|$$

This part of the proof is clear to me.

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be an arbitrary vector such that the length of the vector $x$ relative to the norm $l_\infty$ is $1$.

$\begin{align}
\norm{A} &= \max_{||x||=1}||Ax||_\infty 
             = \max_{1 \le i \le n} |(Ax)_i|
             = \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\sum_j a_{ij} x_j|\\
             &\le \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{ij}|\cdot |x_j|\\
             &\le \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{ij}|\cdot \max_{1 \le j \le n} |x_j| = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{ij}|\cdot ||x||_\infty = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{ij}|
\end{align}$

We now prove the opposite side of the inequality. The arguments that follow from this point on are not clear to me. Either I don't fully understand it, or there is a typo in the book.

Let $p$ be an integer such that $\sum_j |a_{pj}|=\max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{ij}|$.

Let $x$ be a vector with components $x_j=1$, if $a_{pj}\ge 0$ and $x_j=-1$ if $a_{pj}<0$.

Then, $\norm{x} = 1$ and $a_{pj}x_j = |a_{pj}|$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

So,

$\begin{align}
\norm{Ax} &= \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\sum_j a_{ij}x_j|\\
              &\ge |\sum_j a_{pj}x_j| \space (\text{Don't follow this step})\\ 
              &= |\sum_j |a_{pj}|| 
              = \sum_j |a_{pj}|
              = \max_{1 \le i \le n}\sum_j |a_{ij}|
\end{align}$

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to explain to you, I take the proof you provided and add comments

$\begin{align}
||Ax||_\infty &= \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\sum_j a_{ij}x_j|\\
              &\ge \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\sum_j a_{pj}x_j| \space (\text{Don't follow this step})\\ 
              &= |\sum_j |a_{pj}|| \\
              &= \sum_j |a_{pj}| \\
              &= \max_{1 \le i \le n}\sum_j |a_{ij}| \\
\end{align}$

First note on the second line that the sum do not depend on $i$ so its constant relatively to $i$. And because $p$ is among the $i\in[1,n]$, you have

$$||Ax||_\infty = \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\sum_j a_{ij}x_j| \geq  \sum_j |a_{pj}x_j| = \\  \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_j |a_{pj}x_j|\\(\text{because max of a constant is a constant, actually you don't need a max for the second line)} $$

Comment: Okay, so $p$ is some one row of the $[1,\ldots,n]$ rows. Hence, $\max_i (\sum_j a_{ij}x_j) \ge (\sum_j a_{pj}x_j)$. The maximum of all possible sums is greater than or equal to a particular sum, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, absolutely !